# Git-svn under solaris x86

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Does git-svn work under solaris x86?

I have installed git, but when i want to use git-svn it doesn't work.

I looked up for 'git-svn' package in the internet but in vain. it could'nt find it.

SomeBody can help me please or tell me where i can find it please.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried?  Have you tried running any `git-svn` commands?  `git svn clone` or the like?  If so, what kind of error did you see?  FWIW, `git-svn` is distributed with `git`.  How did you install `git`?

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` requires `libsvn` to be installed.  Depending on how you installed `git` (from source, from packages) there are probably different solutions.  If it's a package there's likely a secondary package for `git-svn` which has the extra SVN libs as a package dependency.  If you built from source you may need to install a dev package for SVN or build it from source with the option to produce the SWIG libraries for clients.